# Input text type showing undefined in view source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have three check box with two is auto selected. I have to display the text field with a label which check box is selected.

I tried below code but it is displaying only one text field and type is undefined I checked in view source. I think there is some issue with `this`.
Would you help me out?

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
     $checkbox=$(".add_student_input").is(":checked");
        if($checkbox == true) {
            $(".students_items").append('<div class="' + this.id + '"><label>' + $(this).next('label').text() + '</label><input type="' + $(this).data('type') + '" name="input[]" placeholder="' + $(this).next('label').text() + '" class="form-control" /></div>');
            } else {
                 //check false
                  $('.students_items').find('.' + this.id).remove();
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <input type="checkbox" name="a"  id="class_1" class="add_student_input" data-type="text"  checked><label for="class_1">number1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="b"  id="class_2" class="add_student_input" data-type="text" checked><label class="class_2">number2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="c"  id="class_3" class="add_student_input" data-type="text"><label class="class_3">number3</label>
<span class="students_items"></span>
```

Comment: Where is `students_items` class where you want to append the html content?

Comment: post the html for `students_items`

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay, I forgot to add. Added now.

Comment: @NarendraVerma check my answer. It works as you expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the loop for `$(".add_student_input")` which gives you three checkboxes. So, you need to use `each()` that will loop over all three checkbox and check for the `checked` checkbox and then create a respective `text` element for it.

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
     $checkbox=$(".add_student_input");
     $checkbox.each(function(){
        var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
         if(isChecked) {
            $(".students_items").append('<div class="' + this.id + '"><label>' + $(this).next('label').text() + '</label><input type="' + $(this).data('type') + '" name="input[]" placeholder="' + $(this).next('label').text() + '" class="form-control" /></div>');
            } else {
                 //check false
                  $('.students_items').find('.' + this.id).remove();
            }
        });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type="checkbox" name="a"  id="class_1" class="add_student_input" data-type="text"  checked><label for="class_1">number1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="b"  id="class_2" class="add_student_input" data-type="text" checked><label class="class_2">number2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="c"  id="class_3" class="add_student_input" data-type="text"><label class="class_3">number3</label>
    
    <div class='students_items'></div>
```

Comment: Yes, It's working, Thanks, @AKA, Upvote from my side for quick response

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you do not have HTML element with class "students_items" in your code, so this portion of the JavaScript will not be executed: 
`$(".students_items").append('<div class=....)`

Create element with such CSS class and try again.